# Adding an error bar to a basic lattice line plot?

Tags: r, graph, statistics, lattice

I am using the `lattice` package in R to make simple graphs to display a time series. For whatever reason, the function `errbar()` will not work for me.

I have calculated the standard deviation and wish to plug this into my code so that I can have a line plot with a standard deviation error bars for each sampling point. I'm working off of this very basic code:

```
none = xyplot(n.avg ~ day, type = "l", col = "#CC00FF", lwd=1)
```

And would like to add error bars from the standard deviation dataset for this sampling period defined as "n.std".